# Drop rows from a pandas dataframe until a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with logged data values. The sampling period is much shorter than is required and I want to drop data until the sample period reaches a threshold. For example this df has ~10 second data. I want to delete rows until the difference between the current row and the prior row is >=60 seconds.

```
DateTime            Value
3/1/2023 0:00:00    0.12
3/1/2023 0:00:03    0.12
3/1/2023 0:00:13    0.12
3/1/2023 0:00:23    0.12
3/1/2023 0:00:33    0.12
3/1/2023 0:00:43    0.12
3/1/2023 0:00:53    0.12
3/1/2023 0:01:03    0.12
3/1/2023 0:01:13    0.12
3/1/2023 0:01:23    0.12
3/1/2023 0:01:33    0.12
3/1/2023 0:01:43    0.13
3/1/2023 0:01:53    0.13
3/1/2023 0:02:03    0.13
3/1/2023 0:02:13    0.12
```

Desired output:

```
DateTime        Value
3/1/2023 0:00:00    0.12
3/1/2023 0:01:03    0.12
3/1/2023 0:02:03    0.13
3/1/2023 0:02:13    0.12
```

I was going to write code with iterrows() function but the pandas documentation indicates I should never modify something I am iterating over. I am very new to python and pandas and it may not be the correct tool to complete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the first column a datetime type? If so you can use the [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html) function.

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='20s')
series = pd.Series(range(9), index=index)
#series
series.resample("60s").first()
```